# Open a FB Page Photo in Facebook app from the feeds in other app - iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, fbconnect

I am working on an iPhone app that shows the Facebook feeds of a facebook page. When the user taps on any of the feed i am redirecting it to Facebook app in the iPhone device using the url scheme: **fb://profile/FBPageID** referred from this [link](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes).

But using this opens up the whole page instead i wish to open the particular feed.

Any help/advise would be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Vivek